# How Do We Turn Off ColdFusion Builder Tag Help on Mouseover?

Tags: coldfusion, tags, preferences, coldfusionbuilder, cfeclipse

We use CF Builder 3 and 4 on various machines at work. When one hovers the mouse over a tag, a little yellow popup appears to explain what the tag is for. The explanations are inane, and rapidly become annoying because the popup appears right over the top of what you are trying to see.

I tried defining the settings in Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Hovers to enable these only on CTRL-SHIFT to no effect.  Perhaps I am staring right at an option in Windows > Preferences > CF > Profiles > Editor, but cannot seem to turn this "feature" off.  We like using Code Assist, but intensely despise the silly patronizing yellow tag "help".

Can anyone advise how to disable that?  Thank you.

Comment: You should ask in the official Adobe ColdFusion Builder forum, more likely to get a response there than here. https://community.adobe.com/t5/coldfusion/bd-p/coldfusion?page=1&sort=latest_replies&filter=all

Comment: Thank you, Mr. Moreno. I did so. If I get an answer I will update here as well.  https://community.adobe.com/t5/coldfusion/how-can-we-turn-off-the-yellow-help-popups/m-p/11614661?page=1#M186984